# Is it possible to (sym)link one file to many?

Tags: linux, bash, macos, ubuntu

I have some large files that I need to concatenate into one giant file to put through a software package that does not accept stdin. I would rather not duplicate the content of existing files on the hard drive if necessary, and am looking for a shortcut that basically does `cat files*.txt` silently when opened.

Comment: Why don't you just write a simple script that does `cat files*.txt`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [process substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html#Process-Substitution) to make the output of a command appear to be a file.

```
some_command <(cat files*.txt)
```

But if the application reads from standard input, you can just pipe it:

```
cat files*.txt | some_command
```

Comment: Process substitution is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Another solution I just discovered, using named pipes...

`mkfifo files.star.txt 
chmod 666 files.star.txt 
cat files*.txt > files.star.txt & 
some_command files.star.txt`